# Is it possible to make LyX generate clickable hyperlinks into the PDF result?

Tags: pdf, lyx, links

Is there a way in LyX to set up a) a reference to a web resource by URL, b) a reference to another location in the same document, in a manner that turns the reference to a clickable link in the resulting PDF?

From the LyX manuals, it seems that this is not possible directly with LyX commands and buttons, but this sounds odd. If it’s not possible, what’s the simplest way of doing this via insertion of TeX code?

Comment: Doing it directly in LaTeX is as simple as `\href[options]{URL}{text}`, see also the other macros for similar purposes http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-130004.

Comment: Note that you’ll need [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [LyX FAQ](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF#clickurls), you have to enable [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) support in the document settings under PDF properties.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I still don’t see how to make it work. In setting up a reference, I don’t see any option for making it a hyperlink.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That happens automatically. With `hyperref` enabled, all cross references, citations and URLs (inserted with Insert --> URL) are turned into clickable links in the PDF.

Comment: Works for external links on Adobe Reader (but oddly not in Foxit Reader). For internal links, i.e. cross-references (defined as Formatted reference, right? other options don’t seem to make sense here).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Perhaps Foxit has an option for disabling hyperlinks. Works fine here (note, only the number is hyperlinked in a formatted reference, not the preceding text, e.g. "equation" in "equation (1)" is not clickable). Why wouldn't other options make sense?

Comment: OK, thanks, I guess need to study the LyX cross-referencing more.

Comment: I was slightly stuck too when I switched to Foxit reader. I found the simple solution: "Make sure your current cursor is in Hand tool mode before clicking the links. You can find the Hand tool under HOME menu in Foxit Reader." -- Foxit reader.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the menubar go to
   `Document>Settings>PDF` properties
   tick `[Use Hyperref support]` add the title, author details
2. In the document:
   `float:Figure` should contain `figure` and the `label` (you can add label at the caption)
3. To refer the figure number: type `Figure.`
   and then  `Insert cross-reference >` select the label

This should work.